# How to create HTML reporting in Python unit test?

Tags: python, html, appium, python-unittest

I'm automating mobile app with Appium and Python. I need to get a HTML report for the test results. 
What I need is to save test results in Html files, for human readable presentation of results. I have tried out a few ways, but nothing worked for me.

Anyone knows how to do it? Thanks in advance.

```
import os, sys
import glob
import unittest
from appium import webdriver
from time import sleep

PLATFORM_VERSION = '5.1.1'


class EntranceTests(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    print 'commandline args',sys.argv[1]
    desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
    desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '5.1.1'
    desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'CooTel S32'   
    desired_caps['udid'] = sys.argv[1] 
    desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.android.systemui'
    desired_caps['appActivity'] = ' '
    url = "http://localhost:{}/wd/hub".format(sys.argv[2])
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote(url, desired_caps)


def data_connection(self):
    self.driver.orientation = "PORTRAIT"
    self.driver.swipe(340, 1, 340, 800, 2000)

    notification = self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.android.systemui:id/header')
    notification.click()

    try:
            wifi = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class,"android.widget.TextView") and contains(@text, "WLAN")]')
            wifi.is_displayed()
            print 'Wifi is switched off'

            mobiledata = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, "Mobile data")]')
            mobiledata.click()
            print 'SUCCESS! Switch on Mobile data'
            sleep(5)

    except:
            print 'Wifi is switched on'

            wifi_off = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class,"android.widget.ImageView") and contains(@index, "0")]')
            wifi_off.click()
            print 'SUCCESS! Switch off Wifi'

            mobiledata = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, "Mobile data")]')
            mobiledata.click()
            print 'SUCCESS! Switch on Mobile data'
            sleep(5)


def testcase_dataAndWifi(self):
    self.data_connection()


def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(EntranceTests)
result = str(unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite))
```

Comment: [`html-testRunner`](https://pypi.org/project/html-testRunner/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use nose-html-reporting module(pip install nose-html-reporting) for generating HTML reports while using python unittest framework.

Please refer below link for more information:
https://pypi.org/project/nose-html-reporting/